# confusion on a const function that is calling a non-const function

Tags: c++, constants

Basically there are three classes I defined: `paralelogram`, `point` and `line` classes, and `paralelogram` has some `vector`s of `point`s and `line`s, and in the `paralelogram` class I am defining a `compute_area` function as

```
double Paralelogram::compute_area() const
{
  assert( !points.empty() );
  double h = points[3].distance_to_line( lines[0] ); // point[3] is the last point in
                                                     // the vector however it is not a
                                                     // const object, and this gives a
                                                     // compile time error
  double base = points[0].distance_to_point( points[1] );
  return base*h;
}
```

Edit `distance_to_line` function is non-`const`

```
double Point::distance_to_line(Line& l)
{
  return l.distance_to_point(*this);
}
```

deleting the `const` from the function definition and declaration solves the problem, however my reasoning, while coding, was `compute_area` does not modify the object so it can be `const`, however this is right as long as it operates on `const` objects and calls functions of `const` objects, right?

If the `point` objects are not `const` also, this is not valid anymore. And since they are not `const` that is the reason why it works after the `const` removal.

This is a puzzling point for me where I do not modify the object however the objects it uses gives the problem and moreover what I am thinking I am still not changing those objects as well, but apparently there is a confusion in my `const` understanding. One more thing, is this somehow related to the `this` pointer of the `Paralelogram` class if yes can you clarify?

Comment: Your `distance_to_line` function is a non-const function, right?

Comment: Yes, I did an edit on the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a const function, types of every member becomes const in such a way that you **cannot** modify them (unless they're declared `mutable`), nor can you call any non-const function using them.

It seems that in your code, `distance_to_line` is non-const function, but you're calling it from a `const` function, that means inside const function `points[3]` and `points[0]` becomes const object, so you cannot call non-const function (which I believe `distance_to_line` is) on const object.

--

EDIT:

You need to make `distance_to_line` a const function, and since this function calls  `distance_to_point`, you've to make even `distance_to_point` const function.

Answer (score 1):

To make a member function const, you don't need to make the member variables const as well.  You just need to ensure that your const function does not modify any of the member variables of the class.

Have you tried making the `distance_to_line()` function const on the point class?  If that works, you'll also probably need to make `distance_to_point()` const as well.  If these aren't const, the compiler can't ensure that the calling function is also const.

Answer (score 1):

Make `distance_to_line()` and `distance_to_point()` const and your error will go away.

Answer (score 1):

By declaring the function `const`, you're also restricting your access to any members - they'll be treated as if they were `const` as well. Since you can't call a non-const member function on a const object, those calls will fail.